# API caching for next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm building an app with Next.js... we have 100k+ pages and content changes daily, so using SSR and getServerSideProps.

Some of our data is coming from a headless CMS provider that charges by the request.  I'd like to cache the API responses from this server for 24hrs.

What is the best way of going about this?

Is there a common library most folks use to do this?

Just looking for suggestions of approaches I should investigate (or great examples of how to do this).

Comment: What did you end up going with, solution wise?

Answer (score 42):

I used this npm package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache

And then something like this:

```
import cacheData from "memory-cache";

async function fetchWithCache(url, options) {
    const value = cacheData.get(url);
    if (value) {
        return value;
    } else {
        const hours = 24;
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const data = await res.json();
        cacheData.put(url, data, hours * 1000 * 60 * 60);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Then if you want to fetch something with using the cache just call this function. Or it can be used as a midware in the requests. It checks if the data is already in the cache and returns it, or if not - it puts the data into the cache under the key. The key can be anything, I am using the url for instance.

Comment: This makes caching so easy! Thank you !!

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work in production.
Vercel API uses Serverless Stateless Functions and have a maximum execution duration.
I did some tests and the cache does not persist for the configured time.

Comment: An in-memory cache would not work with NextJS deployed via serveless functions or if it was deployed into a load-balanced configuration through Kubernetes or something similar.  The cache would be limited to the pod/container it was running on.

Answer (score 17):

In addition to Tobias Lins' answer:

At least if deploying on Vercel, you can use set Cache-Control headers in getStaticProps, getServerSideProps, API routes, etc to cache responses on Vercel's edge network. This solution does not require any additional dependencies and very minimal code.

[api route example - source Vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-caching)

```
// pages/api/user.js

export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 's-maxage=86400');
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' });
}
```

[Example in getServerSideProps - Source NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/going-to-production)

```
// This value is considered fresh for ten seconds (s-maxage=10).
// If a request is repeated within the next 10 seconds, the previously
// cached value will still be fresh. If the request is repeated before 59 seconds,
// the cached value will be stale but still render (stale-while-revalidate=59).
//
// In the background, a revalidation request will be made to populate the cache
// with a fresh value. If you refresh the page, you will see the new value.
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
  res.setHeader(
    'Cache-Control',
    'public, s-maxage=10, stale-while-revalidate=59'
  )

  return {
    props: {},
  }
}
```

I believe you'd want to use:

```
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 's-maxage=1440000')
```

Here are some other useful links for caching on Vercel:

- https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-caching
- https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/overview
- https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/caching
- https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/headers

For your specific case, you also may want to look into using getStaticPaths with getStaticProps. You can use `fallback: true` on getStaticPaths to only build pages when they're visited (you can still build your post popular pages at initial build time).

- https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required

I know this is an old post, but for others googling (at least those deploying on Vercel), these solutions should help where revalidate in getStaticProps does not.

Comment: I am not sure if this answers the question. I might be getting wrong, but the OP wants to cache the response from a system downstream of next.js, whereas this answer caches the responses of next.js itself.

Imagine that in order to build the page you need to get a promotional banner from a CMS. You don't want 10000 users to be fetching the same banner, you want the banner to stay on the next.js server and be pulled from the disk, only renewing occasionally.

Comment: This solution is not for third party apis.

Answer (score 10):

You could use `getStaticProps` from Next.js for SSG

They currently have a `revalidate` property that you can return, that defines how often the content should be re-fetched.

Take a look here:
https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-5#stable-incremental-static-regeneration

Comment: `revalidate` is released stable https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-5#stable-incremental-static-regeneration

Comment: If you have, say, several hundred--or only just a few pages making this API call--inside of `getStaticProps()` and an API that limits calls per second, wouldn't building the app cause the API to called for each page with the call? If this is the case, and typically these pages build in under 1 second, you'd end up exceeding allowed calls per second.

Comment: @J.AdamConnor Not sure I follow, the page will build - then get cached. If another request comes in for that page, it will serve the "cached" version and not re-build it. If the revalidate has expired, then it will build a new cached page. in the background. Am I incorrect, as this seems like it would work. Can you explain further?

Comment: @J.AdamConnor Ok, I see what you are saying.. but wouldn't that also be the case for SSR pages? If you get like 20 people hitting any of those pages within "x" amount of time, then the CMS company would throttle you cause you went over the 10 requests (or whatever it is) within 1 second. That IS a consideration.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we did it without any 3rd party libraries, as in our use-case we only had to cache a relatively smaller amount of global data(header/footer menus) which was shared across the site.

The data was coming from a CMS via GraphQL.

We ran an async method `getGlobalData` on each page from on `getStaticProps` method and then returned the cached data to the page component via `props`.

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

// Cache files are stored inside ./next folder
const CACHE_PATH = path.join(__dirname, 'globalData.json');

export default async function getGlobalData() {
  let cachedData;

  // #1 - Look for cached data first
  try {
    cachedData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(CACHE_PATH, 'utf8'));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('❌ CACHE NOT INITIALIZED');
  }

  // #2 - Create Cache file if it doesn't exist
  if (!cachedData) {
    // Call your APIs to-be-cached here
    const data = await fetchGlobalData();

    // Store data in cache files
    // this always rewrites/overwrites the previous file
    try {
      await fs.writeFileSync(
        CACHE_PATH,
        JSON.stringify(data),
        err =>throw err
      );
      console.log(' CACHE FILE WRITTEN SUCCESSFULLY');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('❌ ERROR WRITING MEMBERS CACHE TO FILE\n', error);
    }

    cachedData = data;
  }

  return cachedData;
}
```

Call `getGlobalData` method from `getStaticProps`.

```
export async function getStaticProps({ preview = false }) {

    const globalData = await getGlobalData();

    // call other page-specific/non-shared APIs here
    // ...

    return { props: { globalData } };

}
```

References

1. https://flaviocopes.com/nextjs-cache-data-globally/

Note if you get an error saying `fs` or `path` is unknown or invalid, then please understand that, the above code is supposed to be running or referenced "serverside" i.e only inside `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`. If you import and reference it "browser-side", say somewhere inside your components or on the page (other than methods mentioned above), then you will get an error, as there is no filesystem(fs) or path modules on browser. They are only available on node.

Comment: This would also not work with serverless deployments I believe.