# Next js application build, optimize same call being made on every page

Tags: next.js

So I'm creating an application with next.js and want to use ISR on many pages. But the application has 2-3 API calls which are called from every page like header CMS content, footer CMS content and site configurations. So when the Next.js build is executed, these APIs will be invoked for every page being built as they are being invoked in the `getStaticProps` method of every page.

However, during the few mins of the build run, the API content is not expected to change much. Is there a way to call the API once, and use that response for every page during the build?

Comment: Call the api 1 time. Save response into context when component mounts. Reuse it everywhere you want.

Comment: Does the context work on server side during the build?

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [API caching for next JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62005208/api-caching-for-next-js)? There's no built-in way to optimise it, but you can implement your own caching logic for requests made at build time.