# Cache external API calls on build using getStaticProps in NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I want to build 10.000+ static pages with data that is stored in a Google Sheet. However, the Google Sheet is really slow in its response which is why I tried to cache the response and serve it in an internal API instead. But in the build process, it seems like the cached response is not being used as it takes around 3 seconds to build each page. Is there a way to achieve this or do I need to use another "database"? Thanks

```
// pages/[skill]/index.tsx

import { fetchWithCache } from '../api/googlesheet'

export async function getStaticProps() {

  const rows = await fetchWithCache();

  return { props: { data: rows } }
}
```

```
// pages/api/googlesheet.ts

import { GoogleSpreadsheet } from 'google-spreadsheet';
import cacheData from "memory-cache";

export async function fetchWithCache() {
  const SHEET_ID = 'sheetid'
  const value = cacheData.get(SHEET_ID);

  if (value) {
      return value;
  } else {
      const hours = 24;
      const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(SHEET_ID);
      doc.useApiKey('API_KEY');
    
      await doc.loadInfo();
    
      const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];
      const rows = await sheet.getRows();

      const formattedRows = rows.map((row: any) => { 
        return { skill: row.skill, role: row.role, url: row.url }
      });

      cacheData.put(SHEET_ID, formattedRows, hours * 1000 * 60 * 60);

      return formattedRows;
  }
}
```

Comment: That approach seems to be valid, as described in [API caching for next JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62005208/api-caching-for-next-js). Did you try debugging the issue? Is the data not getting cached properly?