# Using getStaticProps in Middleware.js

Tags: next.js, middleware, next.js13

Is there any way to use getStaticProps inside of the middleware.js file in Next JS?

I want to hit an API endpoint from inside my middleware.js.

The API gives back my list of redirects and if it matches to the current route, I can use the midleware.js to redirect accordingly.
I don't want to hit the API endpoint on every page load though.
I thought I could use getStaticProps with the revalidate property set to only hit the API endpoint x amount of times per day.

Is there some way I can use getStaticProps from inside my midleware.js file?

Comment: You cannot reference it in the middleware.js as mentioned [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#where-can-i-use-getstaticprops). Also, why would you git an api endpoint for a list of redirects in your middleware? Consider the matcher property on the config object inside the middleware file (refer to the middleware docs). Also, can't you store the list in the middleware file as well? I assume the list won't change often and if it does, it will be done manually either way, why not just store it in a constant variable?

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming getStaticProps doesn't run inside the middleware file for me. 
The redirects list will potentially be updated/amended multiple times per day by a third party using a CMS and I don't want to redeploy the site every time it's amended.
I think I will just bite the bullet and hit the API endpoint on every page redirect in the middleware.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a package called memory-cache thanks to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62005551/8193573

This method allowed me to limit my API requests from inside my middleware.tsx file so I didn't need getStaticProps in the end.